# Не работает background-image

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, почему-то не работает свойство background-image. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так? Может что-то недоглядел? Заранее спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не стоит показывать код скриншотами.

Comment: Добавьте код в тело вопроса виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку [edit], расположенную под метками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле стилей пути задаются относительно места нахождения самого этого файла. Таким образом браузер запрашивает фон из папки `css/img/fitness.png`. Чтобы убедиться в этом зайдите в инструменты разработчика, откройте раздел с запросами и обновите страницу. В запросе изображения будет ошибка 404 и будет указан путь по которому была попытка получить этот файл. Чтобы это исправить задайте путь фона так `../img/fitness.png` (*Я предположил что папка img находится в том же каталоге что и папка со стилями. Учтите этот момент если мое предположение не верно*).

Comment: Спасибо, Вы оказались правы

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте кавычки в строке:

```
background-image: url("img/fitness.png");
```

Также, убедитесь, правильно ли указан путь к файлу.

---

Если не сработало, то, скорее всего, в строках файла `index.html`

```
...
<div class="section section_blue">
    <div class="container">
...
```

твой блок `container` закрывает содержимое блока `section_blue`, и картинку не видно. Чтобы это исправить, попробуй объединить эти два блока.